# Argparse: too few arguments translation API

Tags: python, api, argparse

I am using a google translation API and it is showing error:

```
translate boy -d french
usage: [-h] [-d DEST] [-s SRC] [-c] text
: error: too few arguments
```

The code of API is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import argparse
import sys
from googletrans import Translator

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Python Google Translator as a command-line tool')
    parser.add_argument('text', help='The text you want to translate.')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--dest', default='en',
        help='The destination language you want to translate. (Default: en)')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--src', default='auto',
        help='The source language you want to translate. (Default: auto)')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--detect', action='store_true', default=False,
        help='')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    translator = Translator()

    if args.detect:
        result = translator.detect(args.text)
        result = """
[{lang}, {confidence}] {text}
        """.strip().format(text=args.text,
            lang=result.lang, confidence=result.confidence)
        print(result)
        return

    result = translator.translate(args.text, dest=args.dest, src=args.src)
    result = u"""
[{src}] {original}
    ->
[{dest}] {text}
[pron.] {pronunciation}
    """.strip().format(src=result.src, dest=result.dest, original=result.origin,
                       text=result.text, pronunciation=result.pronunciation)
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think it is due to `argparse` module but I am not sure. I am a newbie so please explain completely. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You supplied `-d` and its argument, but not a string for `text`.  `text` is a positional, and thus required.  In Py3 the error would have told you what argument was missing; Py2 just gives this generic `too few`.

Comment: @hpaulj OP passes `boy` as text though?

Comment: I supplied boy as text.

Comment: OK I missed that.  I'd try running it without the call to `Translator`.  Some of these google tools have their own parser.  Except the error usage message is consistent with your parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops - I thought this code was your own; it appears to be the `translate` script from the github, https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/blob/master/translate

So there isn't another parser.

Still the diagnostics that suggest apply - print the `sys.argv` to see what the parser is getting, print `args` after parsing, and skip (for now) the call to `Translate`.  And run with `py3` if possible.

---

Your parser with just

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Python Google Translator as a command-line tool')
parser.add_argument('text', help='The text you want to translate.')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dest', default='en',
    help='The destination language you want to translate. (Default: en)')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--src', default='auto',
    help='The source language you want to translate. (Default: auto)')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--detect', action='store_true', default=False,
    help='')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

produces:

```
1347:~/mypy$ python2 stack47849057.py 
usage: stack47849057.py [-h] [-d DEST] [-s SRC] [-c] text
stack47849057.py: error: too few arguments
1144:~/mypy$ python2 stack47849057.py boy
Namespace(dest='en', detect=False, src='auto', text='boy')
1144:~/mypy$ python2 stack47849057.py boy -d french
Namespace(dest='french', detect=False, src='auto', text='boy')
1145:~/mypy$ python3 stack47849057.py 
usage: stack47849057.py [-h] [-d DEST] [-s SRC] [-c] text
stack47849057.py: error: the following arguments are required: text
```

In other words it works with your input.  As noted in Py3 the error message is clearer.

I suspect there's a problem with `Translator`.  It may have its own parser, and maybe even modifies the `sys.argv`.  You could also `print(sys.argv)` to check that.

The error message seems to be coming from your parser, since the usage matches.

Comment: Yeah I think it is working for python3. But I need to use it for python2 only because the project for which I am using it does not support python3. Could you suggest something? Also what is the difference in code for python2 and python3 here? @hpaulj

Comment: In this case, the only difference that matters is the error message; Py3's should be more informative.  I don't know why Py3 would run without error, while Py2 gives this message.  They differ in whether subparsers are required or not,, but this code isn't using that feature.